# Extract data from open street map

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am using an API map ([Get your map](http://getyourmap.com) : this is a vector map and use of [open street map](http://openstreetmap.org) ) and I want to extract some data from my map and add some features to my map.
For example I want to show alarm to user when user have (200m) to railway station and something like that. I don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask a more spacific question and not something as general as to show you how to use google maps.
also you didn't mention if your using google maps, or what API your using.

in  general, you use, `getAddressLine` attribute to get street information.

here is a link to the api for google maps,

[google maps getAddressLine](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getAddressLine%28int%29)

there are some great tutorials out there on how to use google maps and street views, and you can always open a google maps activity, and to see how they get the street name from there.

Comment: I am using getyourmap.com in my application

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) or [Osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) for extracting a region from a file with OpenStreetMap data.

In both cases you need to create or obtain a file containing the city's boundary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i read these two links that you mentioned before but i can't understand it .